# specific implementation of dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I don't know if the title is apt, but for the time being this is my question:

I have entries in text file(which has 2 columns) in the following format:

```
Name     Time  

Santa    1.2
Jim      2.5
Santa    2.7
Santa    2.9
```

I should form a dictionary which has Name as the key, (Time, Count) as the value. In the above names, Santa repeated 3 times and the time difference of consecutive occurances is less than 2 seconds. So the Count value associated with that entry is 3. If such case occurs, that entry should be deleted from dictionary. Otherwise, count value should be zero (If the 2 occurances of Santa happened 2 seconds apart and 3rd occurance happened after 2 seconds, then count is reinitialized to zero for that entry).

Can this be implemented like this: Make the (Time, Count) as the list and make that list as the values to the keys? I am a newbie to Python, please excuse any mistakes.

The pseudocode is something like this:

```
Read line in the file:   
    if Santa is in dictionary:    
        time_difference = time from column 2 of the line - dictionary[Santa]  
        if(time_difference < 2):  
            Replace the old occurance with new one along with time  
            # If the previous count value associated with Santa = 1, add 1 to make it 2  
            Make the Count associated with Santa = count+1    
            if(count associated with Santa = 3):  
                delete the Santa entry    
        else:  
            Make count associated with Santa = 1      
    else:  
        Add Santa to dictionary along with its time and make associated count = 1
```

Comment: Oh, that's a bit confusing.  From what I gather, the `count` values for *all* entries remaining in the dictionary will be zero, so why store it in the first place?  What `time` values are supposed to be in the final dictionary?

Comment: because if an entry occured 3 times with each less than 2 seconds apart, that entry is deleted. It is for that special purpose and Time is for comparing the previous occured instance of same entry. For example, if the count value of an entry is 2 and third occurance happened after 2 seconds of second occurance, then delete that entry

Comment: Take a step back and write some clear requirements, perhaps with pseudo code even, and a sample case of what you want exactly.  I'm very confused, and even though I may be able to decipher what you want after a while, it'd be easier for everyone if you could improve the question.  Thanks :)

Comment: ok... i am going to edit the question...

Comment: just for clarification. you want a list of names. `["santa","jim"]` and you want that list to only contain entries that meet the following requirements: the entry must not have 3 actions taht are within 2 seconds of eachother?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:** i just noticed you wanted to restart the count timer after 2 seconds of inactivity, i will post that fix in a moment.

**EDIT2:** okay, i added it. should be good to go!

not the cleanest code, but it gets the job done.

```
class dictholder():
    def __init__(self):
        self.dict = {}

    def add(self, name, time):
        if name in self.dict:
            if (abs(time) - abs(self.dict[name][0]) < 2):
                self.dict[name][1] += 1
                self.dict[name][0] = time
                if self.dict[name][1] == 3:
                    del self.dict[name]
        else:
            self.dict[name] = [time, 1]
        for item in self.dict:
            if (abs(time) - abs(self.dict[item][0]) > 2):
                self.dict[item][1] = 1

    def get(self):
        return self.dict
```

example:

```
d = dictholder()
d.add("Santa", 1.2)
d.add("Jim", 2.5)
d.add("Santa", 2.7)
d.add("Santa", 2.9)

print d.get()

>>> 
{'Jim': [2.5, 1]}
>>>
```

Comment: okay, tested it again and its all working. please tell me if theres something else you wanted, also - if anyone has the strength to improve this code (i know it can use a lot of efficiency improvement and list comprehension) feel free as always.

Comment: @Inbar...a small issue in the code....If the names repeat(like Santa here), the dictionary is showing the first time entry of Santa...for example in the last line, if it is d.add("Santa", 3.2) instead of d.add("Santa", 2.9), then the dictionary should contain the latest values, {'Jim': [2.5, 1], 'Santa': [3.2, 2]}, but if i execute this code, i am getting {'Jim': [2.5, 1], 'Santa': [1.2, 2]}. i.e. the first time occurance of santa is being displayed

Comment: this code is assuming that every time you access it, (put something new with `.add` ) that the "time" value is INCREASING. i was under the impression that `time` referred actually to time and not just something that you generate yourself. also, from your OP you did not specify that the latest entry was important. no matter though, it is a simple fix, i will update the answer in a moment.

Comment: `has_key` is deprecated, use `in`.

Comment: @skyl yes i knew that, but good catch, in general i didnt write this code very complex;y because the OP stated they are new to python. but if you want to improve the answer or make the code more efficient, go for it!